# Can I use an optocoupler to switch an analog signal?

Tags: sensor, analog, opto-isolator, multiplexer, switching

I have this setup to select 1 of 4 signals, pass it through a sensor, then output it to its own output line. It must also maintain all the signals at the output at all times, using optocouplers as switches for the signals that are not passing through the sensor.

I have three questions:

1. Is the configuration of a mux-demux the best way to select one signal from multiple signals, pass it through a current sensor, and then select where to output it?
2. Is there significant noise or voltage drop that can alter the original signal, when using this mux-demux configuration?
3. The optocouplers are acting as signal switches. Are they the best option for this operation?

[image: Current monitor for a signal using multiplexers and optocouplers]

Comment: (1) Why are you trying to do this? A current sensor makes little sense if the signals are voltage rather than current. (2) What is the load? (3) If the "Original Analog Signals" are the source then the opto-isolators are backwards. (4) The opto-couplers will have a voltage drop and a current transfer ratio. Have you taken these into account? (5)  Can your sensor have both ends float like that? (6) What is your specification for accuracy?

Comment: Thx for answering,
1) i know they are voltage signals but they will be connected to two different loads that's why i want to measure it 
2) The load take it as a 1k resistor 
3) So the emitter should be admitting the sinals and the colecto to the otput
4) i see the voltage and current drop because of the optocoupler, it is causing the utput signal to be different than the original, is there another circuit to do this without interfering?

Comment: (2) If the load is a 1k resistor then measuring the voltage will tell you the current. (3) You have labeled the signals on the right as a "source" so I assumed right to left. (4) Yes, the output voltage will drop. You could look at an opto-FET but I don't know. (5) What's your current sensor?

Comment: Why are you not just using a normal analog switch for this application? (By understanding this, it might help to give a better answer)

Comment: @SadatRafi, why did you delete one of the OP's questions in your edit? You didn't explain it in the edit history. You've also deleted the analog tag and it is an analog question.

Comment: @The Photon I didn´t know a simple solution like that existed actually =), I will use 8 input signals so de ADG1414 (8 analog switch IC) looks promising. With the optocouplers im getting an 80value difference in Vin, Vout using a 12 bit ADC for the reading. I will test the analog switch if it gives less difference.
Have a question though: when the multiplexer selects an input, the other inputs stay as circuit open? so when i close the analog switch the signal will flow through the bypass?

Comment: @Transistor 2) the load will change many times thats why i need the current sensor
4) how much could be the drop in the analog switch
5) ina219
6) when the multiplexer selects lets say in_1, and the switches close the rest of the signal lines, will the analog signals go trough the switches? if the multiplexer leaves them like an open circuit at the input

Comment: The INA219 is €1.80 each in quantities of ten. Why not have one per channel and save all the messing with switching?

Comment: @Transistor, I have no idea about how that happened!!!  I just edited the title. Nothing more.

Comment: @Transistor this is a prototype I actually plan to build many of these circuits for our employees so cost of components is an important issue! Also the input signals for the final circuit will be around 10. The analog switches look good in terms of price and voltage/current draw compared to the optocoupler solution i was thinking. If there´s a more efficient circuit it would be a great!

Comment: I even rechecked!!  I assume I may happen due to grammarly.

Comment: @Sadat, I replied to a comment on one of my answers to another question today and when I went back the other comment was gone and mine was on another post. There may be a hamster in the SE engine today.

Comment: I suppose it depends on how the output of the mux interacts with the output of the optocoupler. They would have to be open drain or something? Analog switch just seems easier which I see was suggested already.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691295/optocoupler-as-a-switch-for-composite-video-sources